# How to access my Multi-Language-MediaWiki through one account only?

Tags: authentication, installation, server, mediawiki, multilingual

I have got a couple different language Wikis like so:

```
de.[myPage].org
en.[myPage].org
es.[myPage].org
```

I have got to login into each one with a different accountname and password. And once i change subdomain, i get logged out - the login is not taken with me.

I am using 3 MediaWikis on 1 Server with 3 different databases.

How do i stay logged in?

Please help me & regards,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unified login on a wiki farm/[wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) is handled by the [CentralAuth extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CentralAuth).