# MediaWiki: Take Login with me

Tags: html, authentication, mediawiki, wiki

I have got multiple wikis. They all use the same server, assets and domain. They use separate databases and subdomains like so:

```
de.[myPage].org
en.[myPage].org
es.[myPage].org
```

Somehow the Login information does not travel with the user, when subdomain is changed.

For Example: Whenever i am logged in as "Max" and change from

> de.[myPage].org

to

> en.[myPage].org

i get logged out/am not logged in anymore.

How do i fix this? It may be, that databases differ.

Comment: Are you using https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CentralAuth ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access my Multi-Language-MediaWiki through one account only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918396/how-to-access-my-multi-language-mediawiki-through-one-account-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login is done via cookies which contain a user token; if the token matches the one stored in the database, the system accepts you as logged-in. So, you need to share the user table by enabling [`$wgSharedDB`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSharedDB), and you need to share the cookie (which by default your browser limits by domain name) by setting [`$wgCookieDomain`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCookieDomain) to `.[myPage].org`.

If this is not an option (e.g. you already have established users in different databases which cannot be merged due to conflicts, or you have different second-level domains) the [CentralAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CentralAuth) extension can provide more sophisticated single sign-on, but it's a bit of a pain to administer (as the big bold warning on the extension page suggests).

Comment: Yea this is what i did in the end. Worked for me. I am actually also sharing one code-base.